# Rxswift modelSelected

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Data was imported and bound using api.
And I want to apply it to the table view and take data to the detailed view using Rxswift when selecting the table view.
But there's an error. What's wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU10H.png)

Fetch Service

```
        func fetchCovidCenter() -> Observable<[Center]> {
        return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: CENTER_LIST_URL)!) { data, _, _ in
                guard let data = data else {
                    observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let covid = try JSONDecoder().decode(Covid.self, from: data)
                    let centers = covid.data
                    observer.onNext(centers)
                }catch {
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Model

```
    struct Covid : Decodable {
    let page : Int
    let perPage : Int
    let totalCount : Int
    let currentCount : Int
    let data : [Center]
}
struct Center : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let centerName : String
    let sido : String
    let sigungu : String
    let zipCode : String
    let facilityName : String
    let phoneNumber : String
    let createdAt : String
    let lat : String
    let lng : String
    let updatedAt : String
    let address : String
    let org : String
    let centerType : String
}
```

TableView

```
  tableView.register(CenterTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CenterTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        viewModel.fetchCenterViewModels().observe(on: MainScheduler.instance).bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CenterTableViewCell.identifier,cellType: CenterTableViewCell.self)) { (index,viewModel,cell) in
            //It's working.
            cell.viewModel = viewModel
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        tableView.rx.modelSelected(Center.self).observe(on: MainScheduler.instance).subscribe(onNext: { (item) in
            //It's Error
            print(item)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { item in
            //It's working.
            print(item)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: The answer is in the error. Your code is trying to select a `Center` but the data source contains `CenterViewModel`s.

Answer (score 1):

`itemSelected` property is a reactive wrapper for `delegate` message `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of type ControlEvent, so there is a really low chance, that something might go wrong. However, `modelSelected` is a method which tries to cast model to `T.Type` under the hood. If we take a look at your screenshot, we will see, that this is exactly what is causing the error.

So just try to replace your `modelSelected` subscription with this:

```
tableView.rx.modelSelected(CenterViewModel.self).observe(on: MainScheduler.instance).subscribe(onNext: { (item) in
    //It's Error
    print(item)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```